# basic boost spirit semantic action doesn't compile

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, decltype, result-of

I am trying to add a greater than operator `>` to a ast: the code is 95% identical to the code in the docs.

**Two points of interest below**

- A block of code where I'm trying to write support for greater than: commented in the code below.
- A single line in the parse for `term` which fails to compile because I don't yet understand semantic actions yet: not sure how to bind the `lhs` of `lhs > rhs` through phoenix and semantic actions.

*The solution should be trivial for regular users of Spirit, but I am still learning, and only getting by through examples so far.*

Any help would be appreciated.  TIA.

**Code**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/classic_symbols.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>   // std::regex not fully implemented in stdc++ yet

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace client
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

    struct binary_op;
    struct unary_op;
    struct nil {};

    struct expression_ast
    {
        typedef
        boost::variant<
        nil // can't happen!
        , double
        , std::string
        , boost::recursive_wrapper<expression_ast>
        , boost::recursive_wrapper<binary_op>
        , boost::recursive_wrapper<unary_op>
        >
        type;

        expression_ast()
            : m_expr(nil()) {}

        template <typename Expr>
        expression_ast(Expr const& expr)
            : m_expr(expr) {}

        expression_ast& operator+=(expression_ast const& rhs);
        expression_ast& operator-=(expression_ast const& rhs);
        expression_ast& operator*=(expression_ast const& rhs);
        expression_ast& operator/=(expression_ast const& rhs);


        type m_expr;
    };

    struct binary_op
    {
        binary_op(
            char op
            , expression_ast const& left
            , expression_ast const& right)
            : m_op(op), m_left(left), m_right(right) {}

        char m_op;
        expression_ast m_left;
        expression_ast m_right;
    };

    struct unary_op
    {
        unary_op(
            char op
            , expression_ast const& subject)
            : m_op(op), m_subject(subject) {}

        char m_op;
        expression_ast m_subject;
    };

    expression_ast& expression_ast::operator+=(expression_ast const& rhs)
    {
        m_expr = binary_op('+', m_expr, rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    expression_ast& expression_ast::operator-=(expression_ast const& rhs)
    {
        m_expr = binary_op('-', m_expr, rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    expression_ast& expression_ast::operator*=(expression_ast const& rhs)
    {
        m_expr = binary_op('*', m_expr, rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    expression_ast& expression_ast::operator/=(expression_ast const& rhs)
    {
        m_expr = binary_op('/', m_expr, rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    // We should be using expression_ast::operator-. There's a bug
    // in phoenix type deduction mechanism that prevents us from
    // doing so. Phoenix will be switching to BOOST_TYPEOF. In the
    // meantime, we will use a phoenix::function below:
    struct negate_expr
    {
        template <typename T>
        struct result
        {
            typedef T type;
        };

        expression_ast operator()(expression_ast const& expr) const
        {
            return expression_ast(unary_op('-', expr));
        }
    };

    static boost::phoenix::function<negate_expr> neg;

    struct ast_print
    {
        typedef std::string result_type;

        std::string operator()(qi::info::nil) const
        {
            return "";
        }
        std::string operator()(std::string const& str) const
        {
            return str;
        }
        std::string operator()(double d) const
        {
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << d;
            return oss.str();
        }

        std::string operator()(expression_ast const& ast) const
        {
            return boost::apply_visitor(*this, ast.m_expr);
        }

        std::string operator()(binary_op const& expr) const
        {
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << "op:" << expr.m_op << "(";
            oss << boost::apply_visitor(*this, expr.m_left.m_expr);
            oss << ", ";
            oss << boost::apply_visitor(*this, expr.m_right.m_expr);
            oss << ')';
            return oss.str();
        }

        std::string operator()(unary_op const& expr) const
        {
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << "op:" << expr.m_op << "(";
            oss << boost::apply_visitor(*this, expr.m_subject.m_expr);
            oss << ')';
            return oss.str();
        }
    };

    std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const expression_ast& expr)
    {
        ast_print printer;
        stream << printer(expr) << std::endl;
        return stream;
    }

    // CODE ADDED HERE ------------------------------------------------------------
    template< char OP >
    struct binary_expr
    {
        template <typename T>
        struct result
        {
            typedef T type;
        };

        expression_ast operator()(expression_ast const& lhs,expression_ast const& rhs) const
        {
            return expression_ast(binary_op( OP, lhs, rhs ));
        }
    };

    static boost::phoenix::function<binary_expr<'>'>> gt;
    // CODE ADDED END HERE -------------------------------------------------------

    template <typename Iterator>
    struct ParserGenerator : qi::grammar<Iterator, expression_ast(), ascii::space_type>
    {
        ParserGenerator() : ParserGenerator::base_type(expression)
    {
        using qi::_val;
        using qi::_1;
        using qi::double_;
        using qi::iso8859_1::char_;
        using qi::iso8859_1::space;
        using qi::eol;
        using boost::spirit::ascii::string;

        comment =
            space >> ("//" >> *(char_ - eol) >> eol)
            ;

        expression =
            term                            [_val = _1]
            >> *(   ('+' >> term            [_val += _1])
                |   ('-' >> term            [_val -= _1])
                )
            ;

        term =
            factor                          [_val = _1]
            >> *(   ('*' >> factor          [_val *= _1])
                |   ('/' >> factor          [_val /= _1])
//          |   ('>' >> factor          [_val = gt(qi::_val,_1)]) // PROBLEM HERE!
                )
            ;

        factor =
            symbol                          [_val = _1]
            | double_                       [_val = _1]
            |   '(' >> expression           [_val = _1] >> ')'
            |   ('-' >> factor              [_val = neg(_1)])
            |   ('+' >> factor              [_val = _1])
            ;

        symbol %= 
            (symbol_raw 
            >> *( string("[") >> +qi::digit >> string("]"))
            >> *( string(".") >> symbol ))
            ;

        symbol_raw %= 
            +(qi::alpha | qi::char_( "_" ))
            ;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(expression);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(term);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(factor);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(comment);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(symbol);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(symbol_raw);
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, expression_ast(), ascii::space_type>
        expression, term, factor, comment;

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), ascii::space_type>
        symbol, symbol_raw;
    };
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using boost::spirit::ascii::space;
    using client::expression_ast;
    using client::ast_print;

    typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator_type;
    typedef client::ParserGenerator<iterator_type> ParserGenerator;

    ParserGenerator pg;   // our grammar
    std::string predicate( "i_.c>x[0]" );
    expression_ast  ast;
    ast_print       printer;

    iterator_type iter = predicate.begin(), end = predicate.end();
    if ( phrase_parse( iter, end, pg, space, ast ))
    {
        std::cerr << printer( ast ) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 @llonesmiz wow - deserves a +10 for working that Spirit Voodoo - I was almost afraid to post this one on SO.  I probably shouldn't hesitate...

Comment: verified to work with g++ 4.7.2 using -std=c++11 - @llonesmiz - if we don't hear from sehe for a week, I will msg u later to use your solution as the answer... ty for your help!

Comment: @llonesmiz (_lol..._) -- of course, _`decltype`_ is cheating here :)  I provided an answer with heaps of information on what was wrong, why, and how to fix it. (FWIW, I mostly run with `decltype` myself these days)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TL;DR use

```
template <typename, typename> struct result { typedef expression_ast type; };
```

inside `binary_expr` struct. Here's why:

---

You declare a functor object, to be used as a Phoenix *lazy actor*.

The functor is what's known as a *Deferred/Polymorphic Calleable Object (PCE)* in the Boost documentation. This means that the expression templates building the Phoenix actors will actually only do actual overload resolution/type deduction for the function arguments *at the actual time of application*.

The function return type *cannot* be deduced (just like it cannot in regular (non-lazy) C++). This is where boost libraries employ the BOOST_RESULT_OF protocol.

> **Note** The RESULT_OF protocol is obsolete/redundant when using C++11, since C++11 has `decltype`. To enable that, on most compilers you need to
>
> ```
> #define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTPYE
> ```
>
> (allthough the release notes of v1_52_0 make it clear that `decltype` is becoming the default for compilers that support it well enough).

What this protocol entails, is this:

- When you use Polymorphic Calleable Object with *`n`* parameters, boost will look for a nested `type` typedef *inside* a nested class template `result`, parameterized with the *`n`* actual argument types. *This will be the return type*
- The actual functor invocation *calls* `operator()` with those arguments. Here, C++ will be left to do the overload resolution.

In general, you are expected to write your functor in fully parameterized style:

```
template<char OP>
struct binary_expr
{
    template <typename, typename> struct result { typedef expression_ast type; };

    template <typename A, typename B>
    typename result<A,B>::type operator()(A const&a,B const&b) const {
        return expression_ast(binary_op( OP, a, b ));
    }
};
```

This works. However, because the actual overload resolution on argument types is done by the compiler, you can change the `operator()` signature to use fixed types:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
expression_ast operator()(A const&a,B const&b) const {
    return binary_op(OP, a, b);
}
```

If you wish, you can do away with (some) template parameters:

```
template <typename E>
expression_ast operator()(E const&a,E const&b) const {
    return binary_op(OP, a, b);
}
```

Or even not a function template at all:

```
expression_ast operator()(expression_ast const&,expression_ast const&) const;
```

Everything is *fine*, as long as one overload matches the *actual* argument types passed. ***The important bit***, though, is that the `result<...>::type` is getting evaluated regardless of the signature of `operator()`, and as such ***it will need precisely the number of arguments expected***.

Note also that you can, in this fashion, combine functors of different arity:

```
template <char OP> struct operator_expr 
{
    template <typename T, typename=T> struct result 
        { typedef expression_ast type; };

    expression_ast operator()(expression_ast const& expr) const
    { return expression_ast(unary_op(OP, expr)); }

    expression_ast operator()(expression_ast const&a, expression_ast const&b) const 
    { return binary_op(OP, a, b); }
};

static boost::phoenix::function<operator_expr<'-'>> neg;
static boost::phoenix::function<operator_expr<'>'>> gt;
```

This works, because both `result<T>::type` and `result<T,U>::type` are valid type expressions with this definition.

---

#### Bonus notes:

1. You had a strangeness there where you said

   ```
   template <typename T> struct result { typedef T type; };
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   template <typename> struct result { typedef expression_ast type; };
   ```

   This is because the return type shouls, in fact, *not* vary depending on the actual argument type. In your sample, the argument type *would* normally be the same, but it didn't make sense technically.
2. You can do things without the BOOST_RESULT_OF protocol if you use decltype. This means you can just drop the nested `result` struct
3. You can also adapt normal functions as Phoenix actors:

   ```
   #define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3

   // ...

   expression_ast neg_expr(expression_ast const&a)                         { return unary_op ('-', a); }
   expression_ast gt_expr (expression_ast const&a, expression_ast const&b) { return binary_op('>', a, b); }

   BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(expression_ast, neg, neg_expr, 1)
   BOOST_PHOENIX_ADAPT_FUNCTION(expression_ast, gt,  gt_expr,  2)
   ```

   This will basically write the functor objects *for you*, including the RESULT_OF protocol bits.
4. Finally, you can use standard Phoenix actors instead of defining custom ones. In that case, there is no need for any of the above:

   ```
   using phx = boost::phoenix;
   // ...
      |   ('>' >> factor [_val = phx::construct<binary_op>('>', _val, _1)]) // PROBLEM HERE!
   // ...
      |   ('-' >> factor [_val = phx::construct<unary_op>('-', _1)])
   ```

### Wrap-up

The complete code is here: **http://ideone.com/Xv9IH1** and was tested on

- MSVC 2012, boost 1_52_0, Win64
- GCC 4.8, boost 1_52_0, Win64

Comment: +1 holy smokes - sehe has an answer - bb later to digest this!

Comment: I am in awe - this needs to go inside some tutorial/docs - too valuable to be buried, lost in SO. starred.

Comment: FWIW It's already in the docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#result_of (which will also show some information I have left out). I just wrote it with your specific usage in mind, I guess :) (also: just upvoting will be enough: stuff won't get buried. I might tag it with relevant boost tags if they exist)