# Use a trait for parsing a date in boost::spirit

Tags: boost, boost-spirit

I have been parsing log files containing dates and storing them as strings, but that is memory consumption intensive and kind of costly due to string allocation.

I was advised to use a Timestamp for storing the date and a boost spirit stream to parse it, so I tried both "boost::posix_time::ptime" and old "std::time_t + std::get_time", but they both hurts performance badly.

I would like to give a try to this new method: parsing the date as plain ints and then use a trait to transform them into a std::time_t. I have tried as much as I can following next spirit example https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/parse_date.cpp, but I am not able of even get my own test to compile. The obscure boost spirit transform_attribute syntax does not help either.

Might someone help me with this problem?

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <ctime>

typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

namespace structs {
    typedef boost::fusion::vector<int, int, int, int, int, int, int> date_parts;

    struct Timestamp
    {
        std::time_t date;
        int ms;
    };

    struct Record {
        Timestamp date;
        double time;
        std::string str;
    };

    typedef std::vector<Record> Records;
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(structs::Record,
        (Timestamp, date)
        (double, time)
        (std::string, str))

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits
{
    template<>
    struct transform_attribute<structs::Timestamp, structs::date_parts, qi::domain>
    {
        typedef structs::date_parts type;

        static type pre(structs::Timestamp) { return type(); }
        static void fail(structs::Timestamp&) { }
        static void post(structs::Timestamp& timestamp, type const& v)
        {
            std::tm time = { fusion::at_c<5>(v), fusion::at_c<4>(v), fusion::at_c<3>(v),
                             fusion::at_c<2>(v), fusion::at_c<1>(v) - 1900, fusion::at_c<0>(v), 0, 0, 0 };

            timestamp.date = std::mktime(&time);
            timestamp.ms = fusion::at_c<6>(v);
        }
    };
} } }

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace QiParsers {
    template <typename It>
    struct Parser : qi::grammar<It, structs::Records()> {

        Parser() : Parser::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;

            month.add
                ("Jan", 0)
                ("Feb", 1)
                ("Mar", 2)
                ("Apr", 3)
                ("May", 4)
                ("Jun", 5)
                ("Jul", 6)
                ("Aug", 7)
                ("Sep", 8)
                ("Oct", 9)
                ("Nov", 10)
                ("Dec", 11);

            date = repeat(4)[digit] >> '-' >> month >> '-' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> ' ' >> 
                   repeat(2)[digit] >> ':' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> ':' >> repeat(2)[digit] >> '.' >> repeat(6)[digit];

            line = '[' >> date >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph];

            start = line % eol;
        }

      private:
        qi::symbols<char, int> month;

        qi::rule<It, structs::date_parts()> date;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record()> line;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Records()> start;

    };
}

structs::Records parse_string(It b, It e)
{
    static const QiParsers::Parser<It> parser;

    structs::Records records;
    parse(b, e, parser, records);

    return records;
}

static const std::string input =
"[2018-Mar-13 13:13:59.580482] - 0.200 s => String: Test_1\n\
[2018-Mar-14 13:13:59.580482] - 0.400 s => String: Test_2\n\
[2018-Mar-15 13:13:59.580482] - 0.600 s => String: Test_3\n";

int main() {
    const auto records = parse_string(input.begin(), input.end());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "but they both hurts performance badly." - Can you quantify that, and share the benchmark code?

Comment: Sorry, not even benchmark code needed. Just tested over production code and reading time has increased for 30 seconds to 3 minutes for 800 Mb of log files (I will re-test and give exact times if you want).

Comment: I can prepare a benchmark and give exact measures over a reduced version of the project if you think it helps.

Comment: Thing is, it doesn't really make sense for the performance to drop by that much when at the very least it removes a (few) string allocation(s) too. So, my hunch is there's more difference at play. If I can *see* the code, I can try to reproduce it and profile it.

Comment: I think you are right. My assumption is that the problems comes with "boost::spirit::repository::qi::seek". When you have a lot of not matching lines (maybe 10000) and then a matching one, the string variable storing the date gets ill formatted and it accumulates all the 10001 dates because all them have a common date beginning. I solved it using a trait for std::string, but I guess that it is happening the same for the stream. This is harder to explain in words that in code. I will open a new question for it showing the diferent cases, just let me find some time for doing so.

Comment: I don't think that can happen for streams. It makes a lot of sense for strings, not too hard to explain at all (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13875183/85371, https://stackoverflow.com/a/21960981/85371, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23955133/85371, https://stackoverflow.com/a/33489791/85371 etc)

Comment: By the way, after trying benchmarking I have noticed that in response http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04fd22bb0c780f9f still parsing the ignore_lines and storing in vector. Is there any way of just omiting those lines from vector? I can move this comment to that other question if you wish.

Comment: Yeah sure, <strike>that was in my code when I posted it</strike>. Oh well. I can't find it. This is from a local [commit at Wed Mar 28 10:50:48 2018 +0200](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15e06670598e1041) I could still find. Note it's labeled "Log Parsing WIP" and the next commit says "Revert to OP's code". So, I probably wasn't too happy with it. Nevertheless, you can see the `(line_record[push_back(_val, _1)] | ignore_line) % eol;` trick

Comment: You didn't exactly link to a comment, but I gather you meant [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502728/several-matches-in-a-one-pass-parser#comment86066779_49503266) which specifically said I wanted to make improvements :) Dealing with the ignore lines was one of those improvements

Comment: I have make a new question about this with a benchmark included. Anyway, I am still interested in this current question if anyone is able to help.

Comment: I still have interest in answering the current question, if we can get the premise straight :)

Comment: A premise? Is that anything eatable? In that case I also wanna one ;-) Just kidding, I do not know exactly what do you refer, but my basic premise here is to use a trait to parse date number by number into a tm struct, and then use std::get_time() and so on over them. It is just a way to bypass streaming and being able to measure this new method and compare it against the ones in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49693376/why-does-using-a-stream-in-boost-spirit-penalize-performance-so-much.

Comment: Oh hum. I have mixed these questions up. I'm nearly done writing up something at that other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting [Why does using a stream in boost spirit penalize performance so much?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49693376/why-does-using-a-stream-in-boost-spirit-penalize-performance-so-much/49702675#49702675) I re-read your post and added the approach here.

There were a considerable number of issues with the way in which the trait and the parser rule were declared.

- notably, `repeat(2)[digit_]` doesn't transform to an integer attribute. I suspect you might have gotten a lot of 49, 50 etc. values (ASCII code of `'1'`, `'2'` etc) and perhaps some indeterminate values too
- you subtracted 1900 from the month value

### The Parser

Simplified it to:

```
namespace QiParsers {

    struct Months : qi::symbols<char, int> {
        Months() { this->add
                ("Jan", 0)
                ("Feb", 1)
                ("Mar", 2)
                ("Apr", 3)
                ("May", 4)
                ("Jun", 5)
                ("Jul", 6)
                ("Aug", 7)
                ("Sep", 8)
                ("Oct", 9)
                ("Nov", 10)
                ("Dec", 11);
        }
    } static const mmm_;

    static const qi::uint_parser<int, 10, 4, 4> yyyy_;
    static const qi::uint_parser<int, 10, 2, 2> dd_, hh_, mm_, ss_;
    static const qi::uint_parser<int, 10, 6, 6> fff_;

}
```

Now the parser can be written legibly¹ like:

```
template <typename It>
struct Parser2 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Record2()>
{
    Parser2() : Parser2::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        date = '[' >> yyyy_ >> '-' >> mmm_ >> '-' >> dd_
            >> ' ' >> hh_   >> ':' >> mm_  >> ':' >> ss_ >> '.' >> fff_ >> ']';

        start = 
            date //'[' >> raw[*~char_(']')] >> ']'
            >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
            >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph]
            >> eol;
    }

private:
    qi::rule<It, structs::Record2()> start;
    qi::rule<It, boost::fusion::vector<int, int, int, int, int, int, int>()> date;
};
```

### The Trait

Basically what you had, but ironing out a few quirks:

```
template <typename Attr>
struct transform_attribute<structs::Timestamp, Attr, qi::domain> {
    using type = Attr;
    static type pre(structs::Timestamp) { return type(); }
    static void fail(structs::Timestamp&) { }
    static void post(structs::Timestamp& timestamp, type const& v) {
        /*
         * struct tm
         * {
         *   int tm_sec;            [> Seconds. [0-60] (1 leap second) <]
         *   int tm_min;            [> Minutes. [0-59] <]
         *   int tm_hour;           [> Hours.   [0-23] <]
         *   int tm_mday;           [> Day.     [1-31] <]
         *   int tm_mon;            [> Month.   [0-11] <]
         *   int tm_year;           [> Year - 1900.  <]
         *   int tm_wday;           [> Day of week. [0-6] <]
         *   int tm_yday;           [> Days in year.[0-365] <]
         *   int tm_isdst;          [> DST.     [-1/0/1]<]
         * 
         * # ifdef  __USE_MISC
         *   long int tm_gmtoff;        [> Seconds east of UTC.  <]
         *   const char *tm_zone;       [> Timezone abbreviation.  <]
         * # else
         *   long int __tm_gmtoff;      [> Seconds east of UTC.  <]
         *   const char *__tm_zone; [> Timezone abbreviation.  <]
         * # endif
         * };
         */
        std::tm time = { fusion::at_c<5>(v), // seconds
                         fusion::at_c<4>(v), // minutes
                         fusion::at_c<3>(v), // hours
                         fusion::at_c<2>(v), // day (1-31)
                         fusion::at_c<1>(v), // month
                         fusion::at_c<0>(v) - 1900, // year - 1900
                         0, 0, // wday, yday
                         0, 0, 0 // isdst, tm_gmtoff, tm_zone
        };

        timestamp.date = std::mktime(&time);
        timestamp.ms = fusion::at_c<6>(v)/1000000.0;
    }
};
```

### Benchmark It!

The benchmark runs, and parses correctly:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/116a51adbc124bfe)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_seek.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono/chrono.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

namespace structs {
    struct Timestamp {
        std::time_t date;
        double ms;
    };

    struct Record1 {
        std::string date;
        double time;
        std::string str;
    };

    struct Record2 {
        Timestamp date;
        double time;
        std::string str;
    };

    typedef std::vector<Record1> Records1;
    typedef std::vector<Record2> Records2;
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(structs::Record1,
        (std::string, date)
        (double, time)
        (std::string, str))

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(structs::Record2,
        (structs::Timestamp, date)
        (double, time)
        (std::string, str))

namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits {
    template <typename It>
    struct assign_to_attribute_from_iterators<std::string, It, void> {
        static inline void call(It f, It l, std::string& attr) {
            attr = std::string(&*f, std::distance(f,l));
        }
    };

    template <typename Attr>
    struct transform_attribute<structs::Timestamp, Attr, qi::domain> {
        using type = Attr;
        static type pre(structs::Timestamp) { return type(); }
        static void fail(structs::Timestamp&) { }
        static void post(structs::Timestamp& timestamp, type const& v) {
            /*
             * struct tm
             * {
             *   int tm_sec;            [> Seconds. [0-60] (1 leap second) <]
             *   int tm_min;            [> Minutes. [0-59] <]
             *   int tm_hour;           [> Hours.   [0-23] <]
             *   int tm_mday;           [> Day.     [1-31] <]
             *   int tm_mon;            [> Month.   [0-11] <]
             *   int tm_year;           [> Year - 1900.  <]
             *   int tm_wday;           [> Day of week. [0-6] <]
             *   int tm_yday;           [> Days in year.[0-365] <]
             *   int tm_isdst;          [> DST.     [-1/0/1]<]
             * 
             * # ifdef  __USE_MISC
             *   long int tm_gmtoff;        [> Seconds east of UTC.  <]
             *   const char *tm_zone;       [> Timezone abbreviation.  <]
             * # else
             *   long int __tm_gmtoff;      [> Seconds east of UTC.  <]
             *   const char *__tm_zone; [> Timezone abbreviation.  <]
             * # endif
             * };
             */
            std::tm time = { fusion::at_c<5>(v), // seconds
                             fusion::at_c<4>(v), // minutes
                             fusion::at_c<3>(v), // hours
                             fusion::at_c<2>(v), // day (1-31)
                             fusion::at_c<1>(v), // month
                             fusion::at_c<0>(v) - 1900, // year - 1900
                             0, 0, // wday, yday
                             0, 0, 0 // isdst, tm_gmtoff, tm_zone
            };

            timestamp.date = std::mktime(&time);
            timestamp.ms = fusion::at_c<6>(v)/1000000.0;
        }
    };

} } }

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace QiParsers {

    struct Months : qi::symbols<char, int> {
        Months() { this->add
                ("Jan", 0)
                ("Feb", 1)
                ("Mar", 2)
                ("Apr", 3)
                ("May", 4)
                ("Jun", 5)
                ("Jul", 6)
                ("Aug", 7)
                ("Sep", 8)
                ("Oct", 9)
                ("Nov", 10)
                ("Dec", 11);
        }
    } static const mmm_;

    static const qi::uint_parser<int, 10, 4, 4> yyyy_;
    static const qi::uint_parser<int, 10, 2, 2> dd_, hh_, mm_, ss_;
    static const qi::uint_parser<int, 10, 6, 6> fff_;

    template <typename It>
    struct Parser1 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Record1()>
    {
        Parser1() : Parser1::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;

            start = '[' >> raw[*~char_(']')] >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph]
                >> eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record1()> start;
    };

    template <typename It>
    struct Parser2 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Record2()>
    {
        Parser2() : Parser2::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;

            date = '[' >> yyyy_ >> '-' >> mmm_ >> '-' >> dd_
                >> ' ' >> hh_   >> ':' >> mm_  >> ':' >> ss_ >> '.' >> fff_ >> ']';

            start = 
                date //'[' >> raw[*~char_(']')] >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph]
                >> eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record2()> start;
        qi::rule<It, boost::fusion::vector<int, int, int, int, int, int, int>()> date;
    };

    template <typename It>
    struct Parser3 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Records1()>
    {
        Parser3() : Parser3::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;
            using boost::phoenix::push_back;

            line = '[' >> raw[*~char_(']')] >> ']'
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph];

            ignore = *~char_("\r\n");

            start = (line[push_back(_val, _1)] | ignore) % eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It> ignore;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record1()> line;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Records1()> start;
    };

    template <typename It>
    struct Parser4 : qi::grammar<It, structs::Records2()>
    {
        Parser4() : Parser4::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;
            using boost::phoenix::push_back;

            date = '[' >> yyyy_ >> '-' >> mmm_ >> '-' >> dd_
                >> ' ' >> hh_   >> ':' >> mm_  >> ':' >> ss_ >> '.' >> fff_ >> ']';

            line = date
                >> " - " >> double_ >> " s"
                >> " => String: "  >> raw[+graph];

            ignore = *~char_("\r\n");

            start = (line[push_back(_val, _1)] | ignore) % eol;
        }

    private:
        qi::rule<It> ignore;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Record2()> line;
        qi::rule<It, structs::Records2()> start;
        qi::rule<It, boost::fusion::vector<int, int, int, int, int, int, int>()> date;
    };
}

template <typename Parser> static const Parser s_instance {};

template<template <typename> class Parser, typename Container, typename It>
Container parse_seek(It b, It e, const std::string& message)
{
    Container records;

    auto const t0 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    parse(b, e, *boost::spirit::repository::qi::seek[s_instance<Parser<It> >], records);
    auto const t1 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto elapsed = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0);
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " ms (" << message << ")\n";

    return records;
}

template<template <typename> class Parser, typename Container, typename It>
Container parse_ignoring(It b, It e, const std::string& message)
{
    Container records;

    auto const t0 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    parse(b, e, s_instance<Parser<It> >, records);
    auto const t1 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto elapsed = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(t1 - t0);
    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed.count() << " ms (" << message << ")\n";

    return records;
}

static const std::string input1 = "[2018-Mar-01 00:01:02.012345] - 1.000 s => String: Valid_string\n";
static const std::string input2 = "[2018-Mar-02 00:01:02.012345] - 2.000 s => I dont care\n";

std::string prepare_input() {
    std::string input;
    const int N1 = 10;
    const int N2 = 1000;

    input.reserve(N1 * (input1.size() + N2*input2.size()));

    for (int i = N1; i--;) {
        input += input1;
        for (int j = N2; j--;)
            input += input2;
    }

    return input;
}

int main() {
    auto const input = prepare_input();

    auto f = input.data(), l = f + input.length();

    for (auto& r: parse_seek<QiParsers::Parser1, structs::Records1>(f, l, "std::string + seek")) {
        std::cout << r.date << "\n";
        break;
    }
    for (auto& r: parse_seek<QiParsers::Parser2, structs::Records2>(f, l, "stream + seek")) {
        auto tm = *std::localtime(&r.date.date);
        std::cout << std::put_time(&tm, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S") << " " << r.date.ms << "\n";
        break;
    }
    for (auto& r: parse_ignoring<QiParsers::Parser3, structs::Records1>(f, l, "std::string + ignoring")) {
        std::cout << r.date << "\n";
        break;
    }
    for (auto& r: parse_ignoring<QiParsers::Parser4, structs::Records2>(f, l, "stream + ignoring")) {
        auto tm = *std::localtime(&r.date.date);
        std::cout << std::put_time(&tm, "%Y-%b-%d %H:%M:%S") << " " << r.date.ms << "\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Elapsed time: 14 ms (std::string + seek)
2018-Mar-01 00:01:02.012345
Elapsed time: 42 ms (stream + seek)
2018-Mar-01 00:01:02 0.012345
Elapsed time: 2 ms (std::string + ignoring)
2018-Mar-01 00:01:02.012345
Elapsed time: 31 ms (stream + ignoring)
2018-Mar-01 00:01:02 0.012345
```

### Conclusion

Parsing and `mktime` have a significant cost (10% of the profile run below). You will not do much better than `boost::posix_time::from_time_string` unless you're willing to opt out of `std::time_t`.

One *notable* advantage of the approach here is that the call to `mktime` is **not** done if a line is ignored. And it shows:

- Parser1:  21.12 %
- Parser2:  47.60 %
- Parser3:   8.91 %
- **Parser4:  20.57 %**

The ignoring parser is indeed **quicker** than the string-based non-ignoring parser now.

Profiling graph: [image]

---

¹ taken the code from the other answer, so it's easy to compare benchmark results

Comment: I may be mistaked, but I can not check this assertion: "One notable advantage of the approach here is that the call to mktime is not done if a line is ignored". I just have created a global int variable, reset it before calling parse and increase it by one within the trait post function, and it always shows a value equal to N1 + (N1* N2), as if mktime is called every time. Am I doing anything wrong or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: Your code is probably subtly different from mine. Mine deliberately declares the rule to parse `vector<int,int,int,int,int,int,int>` so the `mktime` gets done late (only on success)

Comment: Maybe, but I can not see the diference. Here is a Coliru link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/684f1523c84bacb2. I tested with wandbox also.

Comment: Erm. Yeah. Turns out that attribute propagation doesn't "wait" for complete match. https://i.imgur.com/U0hPbEA.png Which makes a bit of sense once I think about it. In that case, you could elect a semantic action: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9a29f895936ef26

Comment: I am trying to use a boost phoenix function with boost 1.53 and wandbox, but I can not get it to work. Functions were only prepared for 2 parameters and trying to use a tuple or a struct is not working. I guess this is more for archeologists than for programmers, but in this project I feel like going to war porting a club with a spike knowing that there are rocket launchers available. Any idea of how was this solved in ancient v1.53 times?

Comment: You could have linked the wandbox, I suppose

Comment: I just copy-pasted your last coliru link http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9a29f895936ef26 into www.wandbox.org, and choose 1.53 for boost. After compiling errors, I began to mess with tuples and structs, and changing the original code with more easy types and simplified functions. At last I got so mess that I just erase it. I will give it another try and link it asap.

Comment: I used last available gcc compiler. Just swithced to c++03 for simulating VS2010

Comment: You can't select boost 1.53 for the last available GCC compiler. Oh wow. c++03 is a difference :0

Comment: So. You can use [the result-of protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530994/basic-boost-spirit-semantic-action-doesnt-compile/13536960#13536960): https://wandbox.org/permlink/Kznoax5SJKIAM73b (GCC 4.93, c++03, boost 1.53.0)

Comment: Thank you a lot. I really hope that some day compilers will give you understandable error messages (for not super-programmers, of course) when you have a problem with templates.

Comment: Consider another language :)